# Is there any language where time is grammaticalised by inflections on something other than its verbs?

Tags: list-of-languages, tense

I wonder if there's a language where grammatical tense is not expressed by inflections on its verbs, but by inflecting some other part of speech?

Comment: I found wiki article about the matter.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_TAM

Comment: Some languages also have nouns that are inflected for tense, but in such cases both nouns and verbs are marked.

Comment: In Finnish, the distinction between present and future is not marked on the verb, but can be conveyed (though not always completely unambiguously) through the case suffix on the object noun: *Hän syö pulla**a*** "He is eating a roll" vs. *Hän syö pulla**n*** "He will eat a roll".

Answer (score 3):

English marks tense in seperate words such as Auxiliaries and expletive (dummy) 'do'. In a sentence, these stand, syntactically-speaking: above / serially-speaking: to the left, of a verb:

```
This does not help. / This has proved helpful.
vs
This did not help. / This had proved helpful.
```

Verb = same

Time ≠ same

Comment: There's also noun affixes like "ex-mother-in-law-to-be", which is future perfect if anything is.

Comment: Let us not forget Lushootseed *ti d-tu-čəgʷas* "My ex-wife".

Answer (score 1):

In [Wolof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolof_language#Notable_characteristics), a language spoken in Senegal, Gambia, and Mauritania, the verbs never change their form, it is the pronouns that have the tense. [In Wolof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolof_language#Temporal_pronouns) there is I-which-is-now, I-that-will-be, I-that-was, and so on, each pronoun has the 5 Wolof tenses, each tense having 2 aspect variants, perfect and imperfect. In other words, you take a past tense pronoun and the unchangeable verb and you get a past tense verb phrase.