# Are there any languages with no distinction between perfect, imperfect, and simple tense aspects?

Tags: grammar, constructed-language, conlang

I am currently trying my hand at making a conlang, and I just wish to know, are there any languages that don't distinguish between perfect, imperfect, and simple tense aspects? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any known natural languages in which tense is never (or very rarely) expressed through the modification of verbs?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/21085/are-there-any-known-natural-languages-in-which-tense-is-never-or-very-rarely-e)

Answer (score 0):

An example is Vietnamese. All languages have the capacity to express propositions specific to times, modality, polarity, and time-relations of events. "Tense" etc. refers to a specific means of expressing these concepts, via variations in the form of the verb. Vietnamese does not have such verb inflections, instead one learns of temporal referents etc. by considering the overall context of the utterance, not relying on a specific grammatical form of a word. This is basically what "analytic" and "isolating" languages are about.